# Facing issue while using php bin/magento sampledata:deploy

Tags: magento2

**Using Magneto 2.3**

**Error 1**

```
Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

**Second**

```
In RemoteFilesystem.php line 745:
Invalid credentials for 'http://repo.packagist.org/p/facebook/webdriver%241f44a7a8e585405db9a679fa76431db357cd88442e6aa69f74f2bef9fc8a5d30.json', aborting.
```

Answer (score 1):

Please try below step one by one:

```
1. Make sure you have use proper key:
use publickey as username:
use privatekey as password:
Ensure the credetials are correct
2.Revert the entry from composer.json
3.Remove the composer.lock
```

Comment: 1. credentials are correct
2. composer.json is reverting 
2. when remove the composer.lock then showing error

No lockfile found. Unable to read locked packages#0 /var/www/html/magentodemo/vendor/composer/composer/src/Composer/Package/Locker.php(152): Composer\Package\Locker->getLockData()

Comment: Run the command 'composer update'

Comment: 'composer update' is working, but same problem is here.

Comment: @vivek give me the name of your magento version

Comment: magento version 2.3

Comment: composer.lock file generated while we have run composer install Or composer update

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/102370/discussion-between-birjitsinh-zala-and-vivek).